# Как исправить код в боте?

Tags: python, requests, aiogram

```
import requests
import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor


bot = Bot(token=tg_bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["weather"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Введите название города")


@dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    try:
        r = requests.get(
        f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric"
                            )

        data = r.json()
        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]
        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
          f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C°\n"
          f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\n"
          f"Ветер: {wind} м/с\nВосход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\n"
          f"Закат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n***Хорошего дня!***")
        await message.delete()
    except:
        await message.reply("Проверьте название города")






@dp.message_handler(commands=["ip"])
async def start_command1(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Введите айпи-адресс")


@dp.message_handler()
async def get_ip(message: types.Message):
    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://ip-api.com/json/{message.text}?lang=ru"
        )

        data = r.json()

        city = data["city"]
        country = data["country"]
        org = data["org"]
        query = data["query"]
        timezone = data["timezone"]

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
                            f"Запрос: {query}\nСтрана: {country}\nОрганизация: {org}\n"
                            f"Город: {city}\nЧасовой пояс: {timezone}\n***Хорошего дня!***"
                            )
    except:
        await message.reply("Проверьте айпи адресс")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Во время запуска бота, он реагирует только на 1 хендлер, что ему не писать, получишь это: await message.reply("Проверьте название города"). Подскажите либо как заменить try except или как исправить код

Comment: Дело в том, что проход по хендлерам идет сверху вниз, пока не будет удовлетворять условиям. И программа заходит в ваш хендлер, который реагирует на ВСЕ текстовые сообщения и дальше никуда не двигается, надо сделать реакцию на какие-то определенные слова или команды.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так бери и отлаживай.

Сразу бросается в глаза, что экранированием параметров запроса в коде даже не пахнет, так что вполне может быть из-за этого.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, процентов 70, что он вводит город на русском, а дальше получается кривой url и либо питон, либо сервер это обрабатывать не намерены. Так что, скорее всего, это ответ.